# Scala Play Framework not found: type AbstractController problem

Tags: scala, playframework, compilation

I have a TaskList App on Scala Play Framework and I am creating the first controller like this

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.i18n._

@Singelton
class TaskList1 @Inject{}(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc){
  def taskList = Action {
    Ok("Task List")
  }
}
```

But I have this problem when I launch my application
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZagEX.png)

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZagEX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have few typos here.

It should be:

```scala
@Singleton
class TaskList1 @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {
  // ...
```

Comment: Thank you you are right about the @Singleton part but it didn't work generally. It still can not resolve the symbol ControllerComponent and AbstractController and it suggests me to create a new class for them. So do you think I need to install something?

Comment: Did you change `@Inject{}` to parenthesis as well?